# VB.NET - Replace string using or statement

Tags: vb.net, string, replace

I am having trouble, here is my code.

```
TextBox2.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace("a" Or "A", "test")
```

Simply what I have failed to find a straight answer for. I want to find lowercase "a" and replace it with "test". If it finds a capital "A" I also want to replace it with "test". When I try and OR statement it throws an error. I am looking for a solution, thank you for your time.

Comment: Here you go, it's Regex https://dotnetfiddle.net/27RUAy so you can see it works. You cant have a conditional on the first argument that you are trying to do. You can also do a new StringBuilder and then do 2 replaces on the characters and there are others, but this will give you a head start. Good luck!

Comment: The amazing thing is that the example in the [documentation for String.Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2) covers this exact usage case.

Answer (score 0):

You just can't apply and `Or` operator between two strings.
If you don't want to learn Regex you can concatenate infinite `.replace()` calls as the return value is a new string.

If you don't care of upper or lower and just want to replace the `a` character (eather upper and lower) you can use `.toUpper()` or `.toLower()` on the input string before passing it to `.replace()`

Test 1:

```
Dim input = "abcABC"
output = input.replace("a", "-").replace("A", "-")
```

Test 2:

```
Dim input = "abcABC"
output = input.toLower().replace("a", "-")
```

Test 1 will output this string: `"-bc-BC"`

Test 2 will output this string: `"-bc-bc"`

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use a Regex like :

```
  Dim rgx As New RegularExpressions.Regex("[aA]")

          If rgx.IsMatch(TextBox1.Text) Then

        TextBox2.Text = "test"

    End If
```

OR use this if statement

```
    If TextBox1.text.Contains("a") Or TextBox1.text.Contains("A") Then
        TextBox2 = "test"
    End If
```

Or just go to the official documentation of [[string.replace]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2) site 
as  TnTinMn suggested , same case can be found there

Answer (score 0):

`TextBox2.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace("a", "test").Replace("A","test)`